# She's got hair of a raven VS She's got raven hair

Tags: adjectives, appositives, adjuncts

- She's got **hair of a** raven

Can we just omit "of" when we cannot add a suffix to a noun to turn it into an adjective? For example,

- She's got raven hair

I mean situations where if a suffix were added, it would create a non-existing  word. In other words, I want to use a noun as an adjective, but that noun hasn't got an adjective form.

Here's another example - "adjective form". I didn't say "form of an adjective". I don't understand it. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Ravens don't have hair! _Raven_ here is an adjective, short for _raven-black_.

Comment: [Noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) is the name for this.